# Select multiple columns from multiple SQL tables in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

A user wants to have the option of choosing certain columns she wants to see in a grid but the columns come from several different tables. I was thinking of doing a join with all the tables and then having the user select checkboxes for the columns they want to see and then it would populate in a GridView. I am wondering if there is an easier way to accomplish this other than my method. There are about 20-30 tables and I would need to do a lot of joins to get this to work. Ideally, I would like to do it like when you use the Query Builder in SQL DataSource in ASP.NET in Visual Studio.

Comment: Use `Dynamic SQL` to Join the tables based on the user selection.

Comment: As @VR46 suggested - build the sql query on the fly based on criteria. That can get quickly messy though; so if I were you I would use LinqToSql   (or EntityFramework) and build the query on object level & use the framework to resolve the dynamic query for me.

Comment: when you use dynamic SQL you should verify the user Input before you execute the SQL Statement because of SQL injection.

Comment: Presumably, the OP could construct the query w/o directly passing user-provided input to SQL Server. If the set of columns is finite and known, then the user input could be mapped to strings representing the table and column names. I still don't think this is a great solution, but it obfuscates the need for input sanitization.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use LINQ for that? An example (if you're using ASP.NET Web forms and ADO.NET Entity framework):

```
            db.InitialTable
            .Include(x => x.table1)
            .Include(x => x.table2)
            .Include(x => x.table3)
            .Include(x => x.table4)
            .Include(x => x.table5)
            .Include(x => x.table6)
// keep adding as much tables as you want... 
            .ToList();
```

Also make sure you have included this namespace:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Comment: I don't know how to use Entity Framework. I am using ADO.NET, though.

Comment: It's the same, just include the namespace I wrote and you should be fine... this is the best approach to your problem, in my opinion :)

Answer (score -1):

Are the columns that the user is able to select from attributes of some kind of logical object? If so, why not use some kind of ORM to build the object completely in memory. This would require you to perform the full set of joins, which is admittedly a PITA, but then you can select the attributes (properties) of the object that will be displayed based on user input. This seems like the "cleanest" approach to this problem to me.

EDIT: I'm not sure why this answer was downvoted, but I'll give a little more information regarding why I think this is a better solution. If the SQL query is dynamically built based on user input, your application is going to be a nightmare to debug. However, if you're always using the same query to build up the logical "object" you want to display, it's pretty straightforward to selectively display properties from that object. Admittedly, the query you'll need will be ugly and have lots of joins, but you'll just have *one thing* to maintain, as opposed to trying to maintain some process of dynamically generating all possible combinations.